# Change autogenerated svelte class name to something else

Tags: svelte, sapper

I have a sapper project. And would like to change `class="svelte-yjl878"` to for example  `myproject-yjl878`.

See one of the examples provided on the documentation : https://svelte.dev/examples#styling

Is there a way to provide my own predefined string instead always using `svelte`?

Comment: See: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2900

Comment: Thanks @CD.. that was  it.